# must be str not bytes error in python3 how to solve the below code

Tags: python, python-3.6

must be string not bytes error in python3. how to make the below code work?

```
"<td>" + str(values['audit'][2]).encode('utf-8') + "</td>"
```

suggest me any solution.

Comment: What is inside the dictionary entry for `"audit"` in `values`?

Comment: I guess your code is `"something" + str(values.etc).encode('utf-8') + "something else"`, so the first and third parts are type of str but the second part has been encode to bytes. if you really want to encode the second part, you should use `b"something" + str(values.etc).encode('utf-8') + b"something else"`. Otherwise please remove the encode method.